# How to view multiple accounts on Google Calendar Simultaneously?

Tags: google-calendar

In the Google Calendar Android app you can have multiple accounts logged in & it shows the events of all accounts together.

**How do I do this on desktop?**

Note: Sharing calendars is not an option, both accounts have access to private calendars that the other does not.